# How do I assign a name to a resource in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to name an icon with a character string, IOW, a real name.  Visual Studio allows me to change the icon's identifier label/name but the property sheet name field for the icon does not accept a string name (it is greyed out).

With a traditional resource compiler, it is very simple to assign a string name to a resource but, Visual Studio doesn't seem to want anything but resources identified by numeric ids instead of string names.

**My question is:** How do I assign a string/character name to a resource (e.g, an icon) in VS 2017 ?

To make the question clearer, I want to load the icon using LoadImage specifying a character string in LoadImage instead of using MAKEINTRESOURCE(some id).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you tried editing the resource file in text editor? VS sometimes seems to block on completely normal things yet loads the changes correctly if hand-edited.

Comment: When I edit the VS autogenerated files I usually end up with more problems than I started with.  I've learned the hard way that it is usually best to carry out whatever steps make VS happy.  I'm considering using rc.exe and including the resulting .res file in the project but, I'd really like to stay in VS if possible.